# Multilanguage in LaTeX?

Tags: xetex, polyglossia

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage{polyglossia}

\setmainlanguage{english}

\setotherlanguage[numerals=western]{urdu}

\newfontfamily\urdufont[Script=Arabic,Scale=1]{Jameel Noori Nastaleeq}

\begin{document}

\hfill \texturdu{   مجھ سے کہے ایک جل پری۔ مندرجہ ذیل مساوات کو حل کریں}

\\

\textenglish{Solve the equation.}

\end{document}
```

This code works fine. I want to add arabic language as well but I don't know how to add more languages using `polyglossia`. So if anybody know then tell me how to add more languages in this program.

Comment: Just add another `\setotherlanguage` command and `\newfontfamily` for the relevant Arabic font.